# Read GPS on C++

Tags: c++, gps

I just got a new GPS to work with on my project and I have some difficulties viewing its data. The GPS is connected fine and is installed correctly and whenever I use lsusb I get to see it connected. My problem is I am trying to write a code to read the message coming from the GPS can anyone help me how to listen to it on c++ This is the link of my receiver http://www.navilock.de/produkte/G_60109/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? What's your specific problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a program called minicom. Use minicom to open the device node for the GPS receiver. Use 38400/8/N/1 (38400 is specified in your link to the receiver; the other values are guesses.) as the comms parameters. Once you do this, you should see a stream of text characters. You might not understand them, but they should be recognizable characters. Once you've verified connectivity, close minicom.

Then, examine a copy of the [NMEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183) protocol standard to learn how to parse this data stream.

Lastly, do some reading on how to use POSIX's [termios](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios) struct in combination with file descriptors and the normal open(), close(), read(), and write() functions. You will then be able to receive the data stream in your program and parse the NMEA messages.

As a side note, most receivers also have a binary protocol you can use to expose more features, but an NMEA parser will be more portable between receivers.

Another note, [GPSD](http://gpsd.berlios.de/) has taken care of a lot of this and exposes a C interface so you never need to write parsing code.

Comment: thanks this really helped but I don't understand what do you mean by use 38400/8N/1 ??

Comment: @zeyad Then I suggest that you learn the basics of serial communications. 38400 baud, 8 data bits, no parity bit, 1 stop bit. If you don't understand these things, you don't have much of a chance of implementing this. They're not impossible, just basic things you'll need to know. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-N-1

Comment: I saw a stream of data but I didn't recognize them, there where some letter in Chinese and other charters ?

Comment: @Zeyad Check your baudrate. It MUST be 38400 (according to the link you posted), and PROBABLY needs 8 data bits, no parity, and 1 stop bit. If not, tink with it until it works. I REALLY suggest you learn about serial communication, as there are a mound of common yet simple problems that can be easily overcome only if you know their cause. If you don't know how to use minicom, try google... http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/connect-soekris-single-board-computer-using-minicom.html